# Using EF Core to create DB and provision shared throughput

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using EF core 3.1 Azure Cosmos DB Provider and would like to to create the DB from my application code.  During development I want to create a DB with shared provisioned throughput to limit cost but I can't find anywhere to configure it in EF core so that when I call EnsureCreated() the database is created with a shared throuput?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately,creating a DB with shared provisioned throughput haven't been implemented yet.You can track this feature on [Github issues](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20983).

Hope this can help you.